# PHP mkdir permissions - wrong path

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

I have an problem and hope you can give me a hint for that:

I have an XAMPP running under OSx.
My APP is in htdocs/app.

Inside /app there is a folder /scripts and there is my PHP File:
**app/scripts/file.php**

Inside the **/app** folder there is a second folder **/stuff** that have 777 permissions.

from the script in **app/scripts/file.php** I want to create a folder
in **app/stuff**

But I got permission denied when I try to create a folder like:

```
mkdir('../scripts/newfolder', 0777, true);
```

What do I have to do?

**Note:**
When I test like this:
*mkdir('newfolder', 0777, true);*
Then it will work, but the new folder is under the wrong location:
*app/scripts/newfolder*

Answer (score 0):

Give directory path as follows inside file.php.

```
mkdir('../stuff/newfolder', 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to make a folder in app/stuff from the app/scripts folder, but you are telling the computer to go back into the apps folder (..), then back into the scripts folder (../scripts/) and then to make the newfolder.

```
mkdir('../stuff/newfolder', 0777, true);
```

should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to create a directory from a dynamic place. You should prefer to use **DIR** which is the absolute directory of the current file being processed.

so you would use

```
mkdir(__DIR__ . '/../stuff/newfolder', 0777, true);
```

assume this line from your question is correct

> from the script in app/scripts/file.php I want to create a folder in
>   app/stuff